# KineticJS with cache: How does it work?

Tags: javascript, caching, kineticjs

I read [this tutorial](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-shape-caching-with-kineticjs/) and need help with buffering stage. When the user clicks 'save', I want to cache the scene, including all drag & drop elements. I really don't know how I should to do this. If you have any experience with this, please help.

Answer (score 1):

**You can use `stage.toDataURL` to create a URL or Image of the stage**

```
var myStage;

// have KineticJS convert the stage to a URL
stage.toDataURL({ 
  callback:imageDone
});

// callback after the URL has been created
// here we just make an image of the URL
function imageDone(stageDataURL){
  myStage=new Image();
  myStage.onload=function(){
      // your stage is now an image (myStage);
  }
  myStage.src=stageDataURL;
}
```

Comment: All right but if you can save the objects so that they are constantly drag & drop? The idea is that when the user clicks refresh, the images are made ​​to stay on the stage. Is the scene saved as picture,  could do restore with the elements?

Comment: More precisely if I use something like that 

json = stage.toJSON();
stage = Kinetic.Node.create(json, 'myCanvas');

Did my scene save as canvas, and when I upload my scene, Is the items on it will be editable ?